# What is the cartesian equation of a line in $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know what the parametric form is, I wanted to know if in $\mathbb{R^n}$ it coincided with the hyperplane equation $a_1$$x_1$+...+$a_n$$x_n$+$b=0$

Comment: First do equation of a line in $3$-space.  In that case, a hyperplane is a plane, not a line.  To get a line, you can use the intersection of two planes.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how i can do an instersection of $n-1$ plane?

Comment: Intersection is given by a system of equations.

Comment: see https://www.toppr.com/guides/maths/three-dimensional-geometry/equation-of-line-for-space/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a line has dimension $1$ you need $n-1$ cartesian equations to define it in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. a line is the intersection of $n-1$ hyperplanes. Generally, to define a subspace of dimension $r < n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you need $n-r$ equations.

EXAMPLE:

Take $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now an hyperplane is simply a plane. Let $\pi_1: 2x+y=0$ and $\pi_2: y+z=0$. Then $l:= \pi_1 \cap \pi_2$ is the line with equations $2x+y=y+z=0$, i.e. is the line with direction $(1,-2,2)$. The parametric equations are given by:

$x=t$ 
$y=-2t$ 
$z=2t$ 
with $t \in \mathbb{R}$. You can see that any point $(t,-2t,2t)$ on the line belongs to both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$:

$2(t)+(-2t)=0$ and $(-2t)+(2t)=0$

Comment: So $a_1$$x_1$+...+$a_{n-1}$$x_{n-1}$+$b=0$?

Comment: To make an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$: take two planes $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=0$. Then a line is the intersection of these two planes i.e. all the triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=0$